# How may I motion trigger a USB-webcam?

Tags: webcam

Is there a software I could use for this? Currently I'm using guvcview but it doesn't have the functionality afaik.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called motion.

```
sudo apt-get install motion
```

when installed you could possibly run it with

```
motion
```

It saves lots of jpg files in your personal folder, when there is motion detected in front of your webcam.

You can configure motion under /etc/motion/motion.conf to save an mpeg movie of the movement, instead or in addition to the jpegs...

```
sudo gedit /etc/motion/motion.conf
```

Here is a link to the Config Options, just in case: http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/ConfigFileOptions

Have Fun!

Comment: It records independently of any motion. How to exit the programm?

Comment: @user262849 Ctrl-C in the terminal window where you run it or `killall motion` in another terminal window.